# Prevent device back button from navigating to previous route

Tags: angular, typescript, back-button

In my project I am using popups when I want to show some kind of information to the user.

When the popup appears, how can I control tha device back button from navigating to the previous route, to close the popup instead?

Code is like this

```
<div class="btn" (click)="showPopup()">Button to show popup</div>

<div class="popup" id="popup">A popup</div>

showPopup(){
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display="block"
}

onBackButtonPressed(){
   //Do not navigate back to the previous route
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display="none"
}
```

So, when I click the button and the popup appears, when the user presses the device back button I want to close the popup instead of navigating back.

Comment: maybe use History like `#showpopup` ?

Comment: Hey Srinath! Actually I am not sure where ou are refering to. Do not know anything about history in Angular

Answer (score 1):

Trick was to window forward. It goes like this:

```
  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onpopstate(event) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup")

    if (popup != null) {
      if (window.getComputedStyle(popup).display === "block") {
        popup.style.display = "none"
        ********
        window.history.forward()
        ********
      }
    }
  }
```

Probably not the best answer it has a little bit of a delay, since first it goes back and after returns forward but will do the trick for now.

Any other answer will be much appreciated